# How can I do a > 5GB commit to Mercurial?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I'm trying to import an existing project into Mercurial. The project is a bit over 5GB.

When I try to do an hg push I always get an error about being out of buffer space.

Does anyone know of a good way of doing the initial commit?

Comment: What are you trying to commit that is larger the 5GB? You normally shouldn't be committing compiled binaries into hg or git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not tied down to using Mercurial, then another possibility would be to use **[boar](http://code.google.com/p/boar/)**. It is not a DVCS like Mercurial, instead you have a central repository in which you store your data, and "check out" versions of files - in much the same way as with Subversion.

The important part is that it is written with the express purpose of storing large, binary files.

I have not used it, so I cannot comment on how good it is at its job, or how stable it is, but it is a possible alternative that may well suit your needs.

Comment: Boar looks pretty close to what I need so I'm going to mark this is the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do actually need to put such a large commit into Mercurial, I would guess that rather than a few million tiny files, the size of your commit is primarily due to a handful of biiiig files.  In this case you could investigate the [Large Files Extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/LargefilesExtension), which should suit your needs.  When you add a large file, it is tracked by checksum rather than content, so what Mercurial itself tracks is relatively small.  The extension will take care of the versions for you.

However, as Alex Stuckey mentions, you shouldn't normally be committing things such as compiled binaries (object code, resulting executables, ...), which are the most likely reason you have such a big commit.  You would do well to create a decent `.hgignore` file (one that removes the usual suspects - `*.o`, `*.pdb`, whatever, ...), which will help eliminate accidentally adding files like that in the future.  I have a standard `.hgignore` which gets put into nearly all my repositories as the first commit, and has served me well.

Comment: I'm trying to use HG to version all my home documents. So lots of 3D models, photoshop work, etc.

The LFE that you mention is interesting... I'll definitely read up on it. Thanks.

Comment: If you're trying to version all your home documents, then taking into account the caveats from @chuzo, you probably don't want them all in one repository anyway - you would more likely have a repo per project, or sub-project if that's still too big.

Answer (score 0):

For a brief explanation of why storing binary files in mercurial is discouraged please read
https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/BinaryFiles  and http://kiln.stackexchange.com/questions/1074/why-is-it-bad-to-store-binary-files-in-mercurial

In our case we handle binary files using Dropbox. It allows you to both keep the history of files and sync the folder between team members. If you don't need to keep history of files, you can use rsync to keep binaries sync'ed.